# Doctrine2 Getting a Proxy when I want an entity

Tags: php, proxy, doctrine-orm

When I log into the system, I normally get the the user record and save it into the session.  However, when I want to become someone else, instead of the entity, I get a Proxy of the Entity.  Normally this would work fine, however, when I save it in the session, it errors out because it is a partial class.

Is there a way to regain the entity?

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine returns proxy when your query doesnt contain what you want and it's named `lazy loading`. If you want to take an entity, please write your queries what you want or use `getRepository()` function.